# Reading a line with using queue in Java

Tags: java, queue

I'm trying to use a `Queue` and read a string from user input. Unfortunately, it isn't working. What is the problem with the code shown below?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        java.util.Queue  q=new LinkedList<String>(); 

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a data");
        String line=scan.nextLine();
        Iterator<String> it=q.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("dongudeyim");
            if (it.next().equals("(")){
                q.add(line);
                System.out.println(q.isEmpty());
            }
            if(q.iterator().equals(")")){
                q.poll();
            }

            System.out.println(q.isEmpty());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What errors / results did you get?

Answer (score 0):

@javalearner

In your code,

```
  String line=scan.nextLine();
  Iterator<String> it=q.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()){
```

You do not have any value added in this queue (q). So Iterator (it) will return **false** everytime and while loop will not get executed.

You need to add some values in queue before calling iterator method on q.

```
  if (it.next().equals("(")){
       q.add(line);
       System.out.println(q.isEmpty());
  }
  if(q.iterator().equals(")")){
       q.poll();
  }
```

And in this above part no need to call iterator method again. You can just store the value of it.next() in a variable and use that in your if block.

```
String value = it.next();
if(value.equals(")")) {
```

https://beginnersbook.com/2014/06/java-iterator-with-examples/ 
This will help you understand much better :).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I try to check all the elements of line by using iterator . could you tell me hw can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helps . I solve it like this .

```
import java.util.*;


    public class Queue {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            java.util.Queue<String>  q=new LinkedList<String>(); 

            Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a data");
            String line=scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println(line);

                for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++){

                    if(line.charAt(i)==('(')){
                    q.add("(");

                    } else if(line.charAt(i)==(')')){
                        q.poll();

                    }
                }System.out.println(q.isEmpty());


        }
    }
```